# ArrayList is not sorted by groovy Arrays.sort()

Tags: arrays, sorting, groovy

`Arrays.sort()` in groovy doesn't work. Why??

groovy program:

```
foo = [3,2,1,9]
Arrays.sort(foo)
println foo.getClass()
println foo
```

result:

```
class java.util.ArrayList
[3, 2, 1, 9]
```

version:

```
$ groovy --version
Groovy Version: 2.4.4 JVM: 1.7.0_80 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Mac OS X
```

I thought this is caused by `java.util.ArrayList`. so I tried to add "type"(see below), it's ok(I can get sorted result). But I cannot understand these groovy behavior...

groovy(this will be sorted):

```
int[] foo2 = [3,2,1,9]
Arrays.sort(foo2)
println foo2.getClass()
println foo2
```

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out in other answers, `Arrays` works on `Arrays`. `Array` and `ArrayList` are very different data structures, the main difference being the former being a fixed-length structure and the latter a variable-length data.

What you are looking for in your code is to substitute `Arrays.sort(foo)` with `Collections.sort(foo)`.

However, with Groovy you can simply invoke the `sort()` method on your `ArrayList` object. Note that sort is also a closure, so you can implement a custom sorting algorithm directly on your object:

```
foo = [3,2,1,9] 
println foo.getClass()
println foo //[3,2,1,9] 
Collections.sort(foo)
println foo //[1,2,3,9] 
println foo.sort() //[1, 2, 3, 9]
println foo.sort{a,b-> a-b } //[1, 2, 3, 9]
println foo.sort{a,b-> b-a } //[9, 3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Arrays.sort() expects arrays. Groovy interprets passing an object in as one argument in a varargs-style list of arguments. You can see this here:

```
def test(Object[] a) {
  println a[0]
}
test(foo)
```

outputs

```
[3, 2, 1, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

Sort directly. Just do a `[3, 2, 1, 9].sort()`.